# Accessing Nested Elements in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am new to learning JavaScript!

I am trying to set up a function that will take a country name as a parameter. The function will then take the name of the country, and use this as a key to access certain nested values and output them to a html page.

I am unsure of how I utilise the parameter within the function, as it doesn't seem to be picking this up.

I have been looking t code all day so appreciate I may be missing something rather small here, or this maybe isn't possible in the way that I am trying to do it.

Any advice / help appreciated!

I was expecting the parameter passed in to the function to be able to be used within the following:

```
/* This is the function that I had hoped would output */

function showCountryInformation(givenCountry) {
    let countryName = countries.givenCountry['name'];
    let countryCapital = countries.givenCountry['capital'];
    let countryPopulation = countries.givenCountry['population'];

    showCountryName(countryName);
    showCountryCapital(countryCapital);
    showCountryPopulation(countryPopulation);
}


/* These are the separate functions that are within the function above, which are working when given info, and output this on basic html page */


function showCountryName(countryName) {
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = countryName;
}

function showCountryCapital(countryCapital) {
    document.getElementById('capital').textContent = countryCapital;
};

function showCountryPopulation(countryPopulation) {
    document.getElementById('population').textContent = countryPopulation;
};


/* Here is the data that I am trying to access */

const countries = {
    'Scotland': {name: 'Scotland',
    population: 5450000,
    capital: 'Edinburgh'},

    'Northern Ireland': {name: 'Northern Ireland',
    population: 1800000,
    capital: 'Belfast'},
    
    'England': {name: 'England',
    population: 66000000,
    capital: 'London'},

    'Wales': {name: 'Wales',
    population: 3100000,
    capital: 'Cardiff'}
}
```

Comment: `countries.givenCountry['name']` should be `countries[givenCountry].name`

Comment: Use `[]` for dynamic properties, `.` for fixed properties.